# Recursively check for condition on tree and stop when found

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, tree

I have a basic tree data structure like this (forget about the parent properties that are missing):

```
data = { 
  name: 'root', 
  value: 20,
  children: [
    {
      name: 'child_1',
      value: 12,
      children: [...]
    },
    {
      name: 'child_2',
      value: 8,
      children: [...]
    },
    ]  
}
```

And I want to write a function that takes in any item, which can be the root, or any of the children, and do some evaluation on it.

Like the following:

```
public doCheck(item: TreeItem): boolean {

    item.children.forEach( (i: TreeItem) => {
      return this.doCheck(i);
    });

    return (item.children.some( (i: TreeItem) => i.value >= 10));
}
```

However, right now this seems to be traversing the tree properly, but only returns the evaluation `(item.children.some( (i: TreeItem) => i.value >= 10))` as if it was called on the root item alone, for which it will never be true.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please update the question to show us a valid example of `data`. Your example has no `value` property (your code looks for one), and we don't know where that property shows up. It matters to how you address this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for pointing that out, made the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get rid of the `forEach` and instead recurse inside the `some`.

I'm going to assume `value` appears on the entries in children. If so:

```
function doCheck(item) {
    // If `children` is optional, you could add
    // `item.children &&` just after `return`
    return item.children.some(entry => entry.value >= 10 || doCheck(entry));
}

console.log(doCheck(data)); // true or false
```

```js
var data = { 
  name: 'root', 
  data: [],
  value: 5,
  children: [
    {
      name: 'child_1',
      data: [],
      children: [],
      value: 10,
    },
    {
      name: 'child_2',
      data: [],
      children: [],
      value: 20
    },
    ]  
};

function doCheck(item) {
    // If `children` is optional, you could add
    // `item.children &&` just after `return`
    return item.children.some(entry => entry.value >= 10 || doCheck(entry));
}

console.log(doCheck(data)); // true, since `child_1` has it
```

You'll need to add back the type annotations, etc., to turn that back into TypeScript.

If you wanted to *find* the entry, not just check for it, you'd use `find` instead of `some`:

```
function doCheck(item) {
    // If `children` is optional, you could add
    // `item.children &&` just after `return`
    return item.children.find(entry => entry.value >= 10 || doCheck(entry));
}

console.log(doCheck(data)); // undefined, or the child
```

```js
var data = { 
  name: 'root', 
  data: [],
  value: 5,
  children: [
    {
      name: 'child_1',
      data: [],
      children: [],
      value: 10,
    },
    {
      name: 'child_2',
      data: [],
      children: [],
      value: 20
    },
    ]  
};

function doCheck(item) {
    // If `children` is optional, you could add
    // `item.children &&` just after `return`
    return item.children.find(entry => entry.value >= 10 || doCheck(entry));
}

console.log(doCheck(data).name);// "child_1"
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for the solution. Although quite similar to @Nitzan's solution, will mark this as the answer because it's first and complete with snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what exactly you're trying to do, but this part:

```
item.children.forEach( (i: TreeItem) => {
    return this.doCheck(i);
});
```

Makes little sense, as you're basically not doing anything here.
You're probably looking for this:

```
public doCheck(item: TreeItem): boolean {
    return 
        item.children.some(i => i.value >= 10)
        &&
        item.children.some(i => this.doCheck(i));
}
```

Maybe `||` instead of `&&`.

Which can of course be changed to:

```
public doCheck(item: TreeItem): boolean {
    return item.children.some(i => i.value >= 10 && this.doCheck(i));
}
```